# It seemed that scroll event can fired during scrolling only when we use div scroll?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

When I use **`window.onscroll`** to listen scroll event when scrolling, it seemed that scroll event only fired after scroll end in some Android device.

But when I listen scroll event in div, it seemed that it can fire scroll event correctly during scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `ontouchmove` handler rather than `onscroll` for mobiles? It's not the perfect solution, but it might work. You can check an example here http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/RFdve/10/light/

I've seen solutions suggesting a timeout, but I doubt they work - both *setTimeout* and *setInterval* will just stop whenever a scroll is performed and will continue when the scroll finishes.

If the first one seems rather inconstant, you can also fake the *ontouchmove* and try to smooth it a bit with jQuery effects:

```
$('window').on('touchmove', function(e) {
    //stop real scrolling
    e.preventDefault();

    // and fake it with animation or other effects
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I considered this solution before, if we use touhmove to simulate the scroll effect, the performance is not good as using scroll event of the browser. So i am considering if we can use scroll in div, I test that android browser can trigger scroll event correctly during scrolling in div.